# Swift Programmatic UI - Why/When use updateConstraint method for custom Objects

Tags: swift, autolayout

I'm new to Programmatic UI, I used to always rely on a storyboard, and I'm struggling with autolayout's rules.

When I started learning developping without storyboard I found this tutorial on Medium: https://medium.com/written-code/creating-uiviews-programmatically-in-swift-55f5d14502ae

It explains that, when building custom `UIView` subclasses, we have to set constraints in `updateConstraints()` method like so

```
class MyCustomView: UIView {

    var shouldSetupConstraints = true

    init(){
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        setupViews()
        // NOT HERE for constraints
    }

    ...

    override func updateConstraints() {
        if(shouldSetupConstraints) {
            // Setting Constraints HERE
            setViewsConstraints()
            shouldSetupConstraints = false
        }
        super.updateConstraints()
    }

    fileprivate func setViewsConstraints(){
        // Adding constraints, nothing special here
    }
}
```

Everything worked fine until I came to `UITableViewCell` subclass. I tried to use the same method here, by placing my constraints in `updateConstraints` method. However by doing so, my constraints were never computed when reloading my tableView. I had to compute constraints like a normal Outlet :

```
class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    var shouldSetupConstraints = true

    init(){
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        setupViews()
        setupViewsContraints() 
        // Layout HERE for UITableViewCEll
    }
}
```

So I'm a bit confuse on when I should use the first method, and when I shouldn't. So here is my question **Why and when do I have to override `updateCosntraints` and when do I have to compute constraints in `init` ?**

Comment: Actually you don't need to use updateConstraints method. You can create two separated functions named setViews() and layoutViews() . Inside the setViews function, you can addsubviews, and inside the layoutViews function you can layout your views by giving constraints.

Comment: Yes that's what I did in my `UIViewControllers` when adding `UIView`s to the view, but when subclassing `UIView` if I do call the constraints methods in `init` I get some errors like `[Snapshotting] Snapshotting a view (0x119d2d240, _UIReplicantView) that has not been rendered at least once requires afterScreenUpdates:YES.`

Comment: Actually the real question is, when do I call `setViewsConstraints()` ( aka your `layoutViews` ) method ?

Comment: Your order was right, setupViews() where you are going to add subviews. And then set your constraints.

Comment: you mean, still in `init`? When subclassing `UIView` I know for sur I get errors when I do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of `updateConstraints` is what it says - update existing constraints if needed. The method gets called by the system when you call `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` and it's not necessary to implement it. It's ok to setup your constraints the way you did it in the `init` method. This is what the documentation says about it:

> It is almost always cleaner and easier to update a constraint immediately after the affecting change has occurred. For example, if you want to change a constraint in response to a button tap, make that change directly in the button’s action method.
>
> You should only override this method when changing constraints in place is too slow, or when a view is producing a number of redundant changes

Your implementation should be efficient which means that you shouldn't activate or deactivate constraints inside `updateConstraints`. I also find this [article](https://oleb.net/blog/2015/08/how-to-use-updateconstraints/) helpful.
Hope this helps!